# Why can't the compiler deduce template parameter from return type?

Tags: c++, templates

Given the following code

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class MyBase
{};

class MyDerived : public MyBase
{};

template<class Base, class Derived>
vector<Base> makeBaseVec(const Derived& obj, const typename vector<Base>::size_type size)
{
    vector<Base> out;
    for (typename vector<Base>::size_type i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        out.push_back(Base(obj) /* copy constructor */);
    }

    return out;
}

int main()
{
    MyDerived a;
    vector<MyBase> v = makeBaseVec<MyBase>(a, 10);
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37e431d3574f6989)

Why do I get the error

```
main.cpp:13:14: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:29:41: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'Base'
     vector<MyBase> v = makeBaseVec(a, 10);
                                         ^
```

Shouldn't the compiler be able to deduce the the template parameter `Base` from the type of `v`?

I can rectify this by changing line 27 to

```
vector<MyBase> v = makeBaseVec<MyBase>(a, 10);
```

but this felt unnecessary.

Comment: Template argument deduction won't work with return value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Shouldn't the compiler be able to deduce the the template parameter Base from the type of `v` ?

The type of `v` is not considered by the template type deduction mechanism when you call `makeBaseVec`. What if you were to call the function and discard the return value?

Return types do not participate in type deduction or overload resolution.

If you don't want to repeat yourself, you can use type deduction on `v` instead:

```
auto v = makeBaseVec<MyBase>(a, 10);
```

In fact, almost always `auto` is a good policy for variables.

Comment: Oh, that's where I went wrong then. I was thinking the compiler considered the type of `v` if possible, and I only had to declare the type if that wasn't possible. Thanks!

Comment: Not clear how the last suggestion to use "auto" relates to the OP's problem.

Comment: @nbubis - What part are you unsure about exactly? You don't understand why the OP is dissatisfied with how they fixed their error originally? Why I guessed it's the repetition the bothered them? Or something else?