# C++ deduce template function return type to be called implicitly

Tags: c++, templates, return, template-specialization

I use C++0X.
I have a template function with a template return type:

```
MyBuffer<10> buf = "1234567890";

template< class T >
T getVal();

template<>
MyBuffer<5> getVal<MyBuffer<5>>()
{
    return MyBuffer<5>(buf.data());
}

template<>
MyBuffer<10> getVal<MyBuffer<10>>()
{
    return buf;
}
```

So in the one case it returns 5 symbols in second - 10.
I can use it in the following way:

```
MyBuffer<5>  fiveChars = getVal<MyBuffer<5>>();
MyBuffer<10> tenChars = getVal<MyBuffer<10>>();
```

But I was wondering: can I simplify the call, for example, in the following way:

```
MyBuffer<5> fiveChars = getVal();
MyBuffer<10> tenChars = getVal();
```

Of course I've got compiler errors.

**So my question:** 
is it possible to declare my templates in the some way to have an ability to use  the last code snippet? I don't specify getVal template type, but compiler should see, that I assign it to the concrete type for which there is a template specialization.

Comment: You could have getVal() return a helper class with a `template<size_t n> operator MyBuffer<n>();`

Comment: C++0X? It was already published, and in 2011.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't the compiler deduce template parameter from return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075703/why-cant-the-compiler-deduce-template-parameter-from-return-type)

Comment: @StoryTeller, It is not a my choice, just a project-dependent...

Answer (score 3):

To start with, you cannot deduce any template parameters from return type in *C++*.

If you want to reduce the amount of code, I would suggest using some kind of wrapper:

```
template<int n>
MyBuffer<n> get()
{
    return getVal<MyBuffer<n>>();
}
```

And instead of:

```
MyBuffer<5> fiveChars = getVal<MyBuffer<5>>();
```

Simply use:

```
auto fiveChars = get<5>();
auto tenChars = get<10>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add constructor in `MyBuffer` to do the conversion for you

```
template <std::size_t N>
class MyBuffer
{
public:
    MyBuffer(const MyBuffer&) = default;

    template <std::size_t M>
    /* explicit */  MyBuffer(const MyBuffer<M>& rhs) : MyBuffer(rhs.data()) {}

    // ...
};
```

and then

```
MyBuffer<10> buf = "1234567890";

const MyBuffer<10>& getVal() { return buf; }
```

and

```
MyBuffer<5> fiveChars = getVal();
MyBuffer<10> tenChars = getVal();
```