# std::map transformer template

Tags: c++, templates, transform

The following template for a `std::map` transformation function doesn't work. If I use `transform_map()`, the compiler cannot deduce the types to find the template. How can it be done?

```cpp
template <class Key, class FromValue, class ToValue, class Transformer>
std::map<Key, ToValue> transform_map(const std::map<Key, FromValue>& _map,
    Transformer _tr) {
  std::map<Key, ToValue> res;
  std::for_each(_map.cbegin(), _map.cend(), 
      [&res, &_tr](const std::pair<const Key, FromValue>& kv) {
        res[kv.first] = _tr(kv.second);
      });
  return res;
}
```

Comment: How do you call it? I'm guessing it complains about `ToValue`?

Comment: You can move `class ToValue` before `class FromValue`. Then you'll have to specify only `Key` and `ToValue` template parameters, others will be deduced.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075703/why-cant-the-compiler-deduce-template-parameter-from-return-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The deduction of a function template is done on the parameters you pass in. Since `ToValue` is not related to any of the passed in parameters it can not be deduced.

You can solve this by telling the compiler to default to the value that would be returned if you call `Transformer` with a `FromValue`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

template <class Key, class FromValue, class Transformer, class ToValue = decltype(std::declval<Transformer>()(std::declval<FromValue>()))>
std::map<Key, ToValue> transform_map(const std::map<Key, FromValue>& _map,
    Transformer _tr) {
  std::map<Key, ToValue> res;
  std::for_each(_map.cbegin(), _map.cend(), 
      [&res, &_tr](const std::pair<const Key, FromValue>& kv) {
        res[kv.first] = _tr(kv.second);
      });
  return res;
}

int main ()
{
    std::map<int, double> m1 {{1, 1.5}, {2, 2.5}};

    auto m2 = transform_map(m1, [](double d){ return static_cast<int>(d); });

    for (auto& p : m1)
        std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << std::endl;

    for (auto& p : m2)
        std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is really helpful and solves a lot of my templating problems. Thank you!